# How to use Global Hook

Tags: c#, reference, hook, global, using

I tried using global hook, and when I typed in `using gma.System.Windows;` it did not recognize gma? What do I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by global hook? A keyboard hook? A mouse hook?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may be using code from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).  You need to reference the assembly / source code from that article.  Also, you need to type `Gma.` rather than `gma.` -- C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay inside the C# world, you are restricted to low-level hooks only. There is some code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx) and [here](http://69.10.233.10/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx).