# How do I make my keyboard inputs work when my program is not in focus in c#?

Tags: c#

I've tried 3rd Party Classes that I could just copy and paste into my application like `UserActivityHook` but for some reason it gives me an error says "Type or namespace name could not be found".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using gma.System.Windows;

namespace BongoCat{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap bothdown = new Bitmap(@"picture.png");
        private Bitmap bothup = new Bitmap(@"picture1.png");
        private Bitmap ldown = new Bitmap(@"picture2.png");
        private Bitmap rdown = new Bitmap(@"picture3.png");
        private int WorkingAreaHeight = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height;  //screen height
        private int DspWidth = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width; //screen width
        private int layerSizeX = 0;
        private int layerSizeY = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
           this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        UserActivityHook actHook;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        layerSizeX = bothup.Width;
        layerSizeY = bothup.Height;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Size = new Size(layerSizeX, layerSizeY);    
        Color transColor = bothup.GetPixel(0, 0);
        bothup.MakeTransparent(transColor);
        this.BackgroundImage = bothup;
        this.BackColor = transColor;
        this.TransparencyKey = transColor;
        this.Location = new Point(1200,460);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
       // actHook = new UserActivityHook();
        //actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        //actHook.KeyUp+=new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = bothdown;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           this.BackgroundImage = bothup;
        }


    }
}
```

(All comments are the changes I made to try to get UserActivityHook to work.)

I've  searched around in stackoverflow and other websites but it's either too difficult for a beginner like me to comprehend or I can't get it to work.

I want to know a simple way to detect global keys from anywhere (like detecting the left side of the keyboard) or a way I can get this UserActivityHook class I got from codeproject.com to work instead of getting errors.

Much thanks.

Comment: Are you importing/referencing the lib that contains the namespace gma.System.Windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079111/how-to-use-global-hook

Comment: I'm assuming that importing the library means putting the file I downloaded into the project folder? Sorry, I'm really clueless on the cs terms

Comment: thats alright, you'll have to do more then just place the dll file in the project folder.  You'll also need add it to the project references.  In your solution right click on "References" then add reference.  In the window go to browse, then use the browse button to browse to and select the dll you downloaded for the project. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QXav2r1piE may do a better job of explaining it.

Comment: Thank you!!
I finally got this to work. I really appreciate this.